# Why does a DHCP-provided DNS IP address becomes a static one in Windows 10?

Tags: dhcp, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 machine which often changes networks and retrieves its IP configuration via DHCP. Since an indefinite moment in the past it started to set its DNS as fixed, despite the fact that they are retrieved via DHCP:

[image]

The initial setting was `Obtain DNS server address automatically` and upon receiving this address, it switches to the "static mode" above (the DNS IPs are the one it received from DHCP).

Only the DNS setting is impacted.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Just a side note, hiding a local IP will not protect you from anything.

Comment: Well, I work in security and there is a surprising amount of information you can gather via / from private addresses. You can work out a topology for instance. This is why I prefer to hide such information for static IPs of servers with known functions. YMMV.

Comment: @woj- correct in that YMMV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While typing this question I got the answer from someone who had the same problem: the `Obtain DNS server address automatically` setting is "inherited", in the sense that if any interface on the machine is set to have a static DNS server, the others will switch to a static one upon receiving the DHCP information.

The solution is therefore to look though all the interfaces on the machine and make sure that all DNS settings are set to DHCP.